# Sort an Eloquent collection by its parent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

this is my tag table :

```
id      name        parent
--------------------------
1      parent1      null
2      a            parent1
3      b            parent1
4      parent2      null
5      c            parent2
6      d            parent1
7      parent3      null
8      e            parent3
9      f            parent2
```

How can I have a collection that each tag placed under its parent tag? i mean:

```
Collection {#499 ▼
  #items: array:22 [▼
    0 => tag {#524 ▶} //parent1
    1 => tag {#525 ▶} //a
    2 => tag {#526 ▶} //b
    3 => tag {#527 ▶} //d
    4 => tag {#528 ▶} //parent2
    5 => tag {#529 ▶} //c
    6 => tag {#530 ▶} //f
    7 => tag {#530 ▶} //parent3
    8 => tag {#530 ▶} //e
  ]
}
```

thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given a model `Item` with a relation to itself:

```
class Item extends model {
    public function children() {
         // parent being a foreign key
         return $this->hasMany(__CLASS__, 'parent', 'id');
    }
}

$items = Item::with('children')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create custom collection class for doing that
here is an example code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection;

/**
 * Class CommentCollection
 * @package App
 */
class CommentCollection extends Collection {

    /**
     * @return Collection
     */
    public function threaded()
    {
        $comments = parent::groupBy('parent_id');

        if (count($comments))
        {
            $comments['root'] = $comments[0];
            unset($comments[0]);
        }

        return $comments;
    }
}
```

it will sort Comment Collection in nested form like that you mentioned
i have a method in Comment model:

```
/**
 * Use a custom collection for all comments.
 *
 * @param  array $models
 *
 * @return CommentCollection
 */
public function newCollection(array $models = [])
{
    return new CommentCollection($models);
}
```

also i have this method for Post model:

```
/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getThreadedComments()
{
    return $this->comments()->with('owner')->where('verified', '=', TRUE)->get()->threaded();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class Example extends model {
    public function children() {
         return $this->hasMany( __CLASS__ , 'parent', 'id');
                }
            }
$data = Example::with('children')->latest();
```